# Obtain certificate path (CA root) from a URL - Android

Tags: android, ssl, ca

How to obtain SSL certificate path (certificate authority root, issuer) from a URL (website) as the image below in Android. Tryed using this information to find the answer:  https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#HttpsExample .
I just founded information about extraction the certificate authority from a file not a URL.
I want to find the information from this picture:
[Certificate path example from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlXoY.png)

Comment: Please clarify the desired output, what framework to use. Also, people at SO (StackOverflow) prefer to answer questions that see some effort by the asker in solving the problem themselves. What have you tried so far?